# Generating a uniform random integer in C++

Tags: c++, random

The problem is that I need to generate a random integer between 0 and 999 (for investigation of a mathematical conjecture). All of the values need to have the same probability of coming up.

I have tried `rand()`, but with `RAND_MAX` being 32767 (on my compiler) this means that just taking `rand() % 1000` leads to the first 1–767 being significantly more likely to come up (and that's assuming that all possibilities have the same probability in `rand()` in the first place).

I'm using Windows so `/dev/random` isn't an option.

Comment: Can't find the dup, but you need `1000 * (((double)rand()) / RAND_MAX)`

Comment: Or [`arc4random_uniform()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html), if you have a BSD-style libc.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That merely rearranges the probabilities.  There's still RAND_MAX options being divided into 1000 buckets in a different way.  Also if RAND_MAX has enough bits, you're _losing_ accuracy.

Comment: You don't mean truly random.  That means something else.  Saying "truly" random as an exaggerator is like abusing "literally."

Comment: Its worth noting that "truly random" and "uniform distribution" are different concepts. You're not looking for something truly random since you are using psuedo-random number generation.

Comment: @user93353 no, that's C, this is C++.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just wanted to distinguish between this and a random number where the probability distribution doesn't really matter. Uniform distribution would have been better.

Comment: @MooingDuck: MSVC is 32767 in every incarnation as far as I can remember.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I checked, I was wrong.  You're right.

Comment: This question is definitely not a duplicate of a question about C.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do something like this using [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) with C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 999);

    for (int n=0; n<1000; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That looks like the sort of thing I was looking for. Unfortunately, I don't have access to C++11.

Comment: @user1546083: All of this is in boost in a C++03 compatable form.

Comment: This should work with vs2012, including `random_device` being a non-deterministic pRNG (base on Windows' cryptography services I believe).

Comment: This solution is OK, but I dont like its style. In fact, in some cases I need to generate many numbers with different parameters extremes, for example numers from Uniform[0,10], Uniform[0,12], etc. Is there a way to insert these parameters when the method is called (rather than when the object is constructed) ??

Comment: @altroware I realize this comment is very old, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19036349/1960187), random distribution objects are very lightweight. They're small, and fast to create, so it's not even considered a performance issue to simply generate new ones as needed. My guess is that the compiler can get optimize away enough of the construction overhead that it just doesn't matter.

Comment: @bindsniper001 thanks! What I did recently was using a function for sampling with replacement from a list of integers, looks a bit more elegant than defining a random distribution objects every time before calling it.

Answer (score 10):

Your modulus observation is correct, and one of **several** reasons that `rand()` doesn't hold up to mathematical scrutiny.  From [the notes here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand):

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced. In the past, some implementations of rand() have had serious shortcomings in the randomness, distribution and period of the sequence produced (in one well-known example, the low-order bit simply alternated between 1 and 0 between calls). rand() is not recommended for serious random-number generation needs, like cryptography.

C++11 introduces [several new random number generators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that hold to stricter standards that would likely be suitable for your purposes..

If you can sacrifice more than a few bytes of overhead (it's safe to assume that you can), I recommend [`std::mersenne_twister_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)

Comment: Just be sure you initialize the mersenne twister correctly. The standard time-based method is insufficient.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to do this is to just throw away the numbers in the interval `[32000, 32767]`, and only apply the `% 1000` to the remaining numbers. This should get you a much more even distribution.

Alternately you could use boost's random/uniform distribution components (or from C++11 if that's available) as these will provide a more sound PRNG than `rand`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that rand() gives you uniformly distributed variable on domain `[0,RAND_MAX]` with `RAND_MAX` being most likely 32767. You cannot map this domain into larger domain by a simple multiplication

```
u=(double)rand();
d=(double)RAND_MAX;
double div= u/d;
double res=div*interval_range;
```

because this would be correct only if RAND_MAX was an even multiple of `interval_range`. however you will not have all values in your larger domain then. But if your new, desired domain is smaller that `RAND_MAX` as in your case, you can truncate uniform distribution generated by `rand()` to your desired domain (what essentialy means reject `rand()` values greater than your desired domain). The truncated uniform distribution is still uniform, so you will have new uniformly distributed variable on your new domain (this will be conditional distribution more precisely). Statistical example:

[image]

so truncated uniform distribution will have another "moments", parameters that describe it (mean, std_dev, variance, etc) but will be uniform again.

Example code:

```
int main{ 
    int o=RAND_MAX;
    std::map<int,int> m1;
    int min=0,max=999;

    for (int i=0; i<1000*9994240; ++i){//9994240=305*32768  32768=RAND_MAX+1
        int r=rand();
        if(r<=max){
            m1[r]++;
        }
    }
    for (auto & i : m1)
        std::cout << i.first << " : " << i.second << '\n';
}
```

result:
0 : 42637
1 : 42716
2 : 42590
3 : 42993
4 : 42936
5 : 42965
6 : 42941
7 : 42705
8 : 42944
9 : 42707
10 : 42860
11 : 43012
12 : 42793
//...
995 : 42861
996 : 42911
997 : 42865
998 : 42877
999 : 43159

---

you can achieve desired result on any domain this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 1000);

    for (int n=0; n<1000; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

however you should really use boost in this case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/random.hpp"
#include "boost/generator_iterator.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
      typedef boost::mt19937 RNGType;
      RNGType rng;
      boost::uniform_int<> zero_to_n( 0, 999 );
      boost::variate_generator< RNGType, boost::uniform_int<> >
                    dice(rng, zero_to_n);
          int n  = dice();

}
```

Comment: Why do you say "you should really use boost", then follow it with an example that doesn't use boost?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley here it is, be a little more patient please

Comment: What's patience have to do with it?  I commented on your answer.  If your answer was incomplete, why did you post it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley and why downvote? you can delete and consider upvoting now, thanks

Comment: @cf16: I down-voted because despite all of the edits, the first part "you can achieve this with rand() this way..." has the _exact_ same problems as the original code.  This demonstrates less understanding of how `rand()` works than the question asker already has.

Comment: @MooingDuck  you can delete and consider upvoting now, thanks. Also when you downvoting, please describe the reason more detailed than "its wrong"

Comment: Surely this "int output = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1))" is what I'm already doing, since min = 0.

Comment: in my solution result is not biased (double) 0-1

Comment: @MooingDuck please point out what is wrong or remove downvote

Comment: Why do you believe that the expression `min+((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX)*(max-min)` results in a uniform distribution?  It's still mapping `RAND_MAX` inputs to `max-min` outputs. So assuming that each possible input is equally likely, unless `RAND_MAX` is evenly divisible by `max-min`, some outputs will be more likely than others, therefore it is not uniform.  I'm pretty sure that's the reason for MooingDuck's vote.

Comment: ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX) is uniformly distributed random variable on [0,1] so ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX)*(max-min) is uniform on (max-min). not true?

Comment: @MooingDuck I think you don't understand. See: rand()is uniform on [0,RAND_MAX], so ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX) is uniformly distributed random variable on [0,1] so ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX)*(max-min) is uniform on (max-min).

Comment: @MooingDuck but deleted this part not to give you a reason for downvote, please consider deleting it

Comment: No.  Not true.  Perhaps this will demonstrate the point: http://ideone.com/5IjSNA -- Your solution has a similar problem, though it's not as pronounced.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: [I'm less certain he's wrong than I was.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8b2c54ea9a6b21be83bda0e5991d106b-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) He might be right as long as `RAND_MAX > max-min`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It changes the distribution.  It's no longer distributed such that all the lower numbers are more likely than the higher numbers, but it is still not uniformly distributed. Certain numbers along the interval are less likely than others.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=99d15e3f1d1a699ada66ae48e4ac655b-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba -- Isn't that what you were saying in your comment to Deepu? (re-check link if you checked it when I first posted the comment)

Comment: @MooingDuck see my edit, what about this one. what you think about this? do you agree or disagree?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley what do you think? can we do it this way?

Comment: @cf16: ....no.  The heart of your logic is still `double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX)*(dmax-dmin+1)`, which is still wrong.  "The truncated uniform distribution is also uniform" is correct, but you're truncating a _non-uniform_ distribution, which is also non-uniform.  The crux of the problem is that `double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX)*number_not_divisible_by_rand_max` is is not uniform. It's the same issue as `rand()%range`, except hidden behind `double`s.

Comment: @cf16: look at Benjamin's code again.  Look at how many times the number 4 was returned.

Comment: yes, this is correct, so we take double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX) and we have uniform variable on [0,1] : do you agree? then multiple of it: (dmax-dmin+1)*double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX) is also uniform, and it doesn't matter on what interval, as I said we might take (dmax-dmin+890)*double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX) and it is still OK as long as result is u.d.

Comment: look at my code, you can see result is OK, my solution removes this problem, I have seen it

Comment: @cf16: `double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX)` is uniform on [0,1] yes, but you are forgetting that it is discrete rather than continuous.  Imagine if `RAND_MAX` is 4.  then `double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX)` will uniformly be the values `0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00`.  If you multiply this by 1000, you uniformly get the values `0, 250, 500, 750, and 1000`, but this is _clearly_ not uniform over the values [0, 1000].  I've looked at your code: [I can see your result is NOT ok](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=050a46b3826bd98e70a3051618ef9e28-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: of course there is problem with domain, but why do you state:  Imagine if RAND_MAX is 4. then double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX) will uniformly be the values 0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00. This is not true, these values will be 0.00001,0.0002...0.9999,1.0 so will cover domain closely, and since I round every double to near int x such that x<d and above points are uniform, so my result is uniform. do you agree?

Comment: OK, I have to reconsider again

Comment: @cf16: Or, just leave the answer how it is right now.  Right now it is good, and correct.

Comment: I don't understand, especially: why [in this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=050a46b3826bd98e70a3051618ef9e28-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) values of 0,1,2.. are not counted same times, since this is not random, but int is simply increased, how this is possible?

Comment: @MooingDuck I have updated again, I think now I know, truely we can't use rand() to create uniform distribution on any domain, but we can use it to derive uniform distribution on smaller domain by truncation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28757/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-cf16)

Comment: @cf16: "this would be correct only if interval_range was multiple of RAND_MAX however you will not have all values in your larger domain then." this is false, and most of the subsequent paragraph is false.  The code is only correct if `RAND_MAX` is an even multiple of `interval_range`.

Comment: @MooingDuck please feel free to edit post or please point out what is still not right in your opinion

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a random number using `rand()`.
2. Divide it with `RAND_MAX`. You will get a floating point number between 0 and 1.
3. Multiply this number with 1000.

Comment: I'm skeptical that floating point rounding issues won't bias some integers after multiplying.

Comment: For instance, 1000 turns up far less than 1/1000th of the time due to rounding down.

Comment: That merely changes the distribution of (0-RAND_MAX) -> (0-1000) from being the lowest 767 to being an unpredictable 727.  That doesn't make them even.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "truly random" in computers. I also don't beleive there is any significantly higher chance of 1-767 (or technically, 0-767, in that case) than any other number. However, if you need "better" random numbers, and then C++11 has support for using Mersenne Twister, which is a higher grade random number generator.

Some more information here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/

Comment: On Windows, for 1000 values, lower numbers are picked 1.539% more often than higher numbers.  That may be significant for what he's doing.

Comment: I was wrong about Windows' RAND_MAX, the lower numbers are picked 3.125% more often.