# Vary range of uniform_int_distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random, distribution

So i have a Random object:

```
typedef unsigned int uint32;

class Random {
public:
    Random() = default;
    Random(std::mt19937::result_type seed) : eng(seed) {}

private:
    uint32 DrawNumber();
    std::mt19937 eng{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32> uniform_dist{0, UINT32_MAX};
};

uint32 Random::DrawNumber()
{
    return uniform_dist(eng);
}
```

What's the best way I can vary (through another function or otherwise) the upper bound of of the distribution?

(also willing to take advice on other style issues)

Comment: You can't vary the bounds of the `distribution` after first initializing them. How you should proceed depends a lot on what you use your random numbers for and why you need to change the bounds.

Comment: @us2012 That is wrong; you can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use std::uniform\_int\_distribution and define its range later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328948/use-stduniform-int-distribution-and-define-its-range-later) (pre-empting objections: yes, that's newer and has a somewhat tangential title, but IMO it has a more on-topic accepted answer and generally gets to the point faster)

Comment: At the risk of being biased, the 2 different questions have essentially the same accepted answer - "Another way would be to add a method..." part of the other question's answer is the same as the accepted answer here. This answer also includes usage, with a std::mt19937. That said the `.param` method is new. Since this question is now 5 years old, perhaps the best course of action would be to mark the other as a duplicate and amend the accepted answer here? Alternatively just leave the questions as is :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Distribution objects are lightweight. Simply construct a new distribution when you need a random number. I use this approach in a game engine, and, after benchmarking, it's comparable to using good old `rand()`.

Also, I've asked how to vary the range of distribution on GoingNative 2013 live stream, and Stephen T. Lavavej, a member of the standard committee, suggested to simply create new distributions, as it shouldn't be a performance issue.

Here's how I would write your code:

```
using uint32 = unsigned int;

class Random {
public:
    Random() = default;
    Random(std::mt19937::result_type seed) : eng(seed) {}
    uint32 DrawNumber(uint32 min, uint32 max);

private:        
    std::mt19937 eng{std::random_device{}()};
};

uint32 Random::DrawNumber(uint32 min, uint32 max)
{
    return std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32>{min, max}(eng);
}
```

Comment: I think i just watched that Going Native stream :) Although, i'm (a bit) new to C++ (especially C++11) and a fair amount of it went over my head :L

If you're sure that there's no significant overhead in creating a new distribution each time, i'll probably go with this

Comment: I've benchmarked it. Overhead is minimal and can be ignored. (This is being said by a micro-optimization nazi). 
Also, there is *no other way* of changing a distribution's bounds.

Comment: Ok, great, thanks very much :)
I'll probably go with a constant 0 as the min, and UINT32_MAX as a default for max.

Comment: This *creates* a new distribution, rather than modifying an existing one. As such, it  doesn't answer the question, regardless of how quickly the class in instantiated.

Comment: Found this answer via google and I have concerns. You are creating a new `std::mt19937` engine object every time you construct a `Random`; the exact opposite of what S.T.L. suggests...

Answer (score 14):

You can simply create a `std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32>::param_type` and modify the range using the [`param()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++/api/a01008.html) method. You can cut down the template noise with `decltype` :

```
decltype(uniform_dist.param()) new_range (0, upper);
uniform_dist.param(new_range);
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm making the `DrawNumber` function `public` for my example. You can provide an overload that takes an upper bound, and then pass a new `uniform_int_distribution::param_type` to [`uniform_int_distribution::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator%28%29)

The `param_type` can be constructed using the same arguments as the corresponding distribution.

From N3337, *§26.5.1.6/9 **[rand.req.dist]***

> For each of the constructors of `D` taking arguments corresponding to parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a corresponding constructor subject to the same requirements and taking arguments identical in number, type, and default values. Moreover, for each of the member functions of `D` that return values corresponding to parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a corresponding member function with the identical name, type, and semantics.

where `D` is the type of a random number distribution function object and `P` is the type named by `D`'s associated `param_type`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

typedef unsigned int uint32;

class Random {
public:
    Random() = default;
    Random(std::mt19937::result_type seed) : eng(seed) {}

    uint32 DrawNumber();
    uint32 DrawNumber(uint32 ub);

private:
    std::mt19937 eng{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32> uniform_dist{0, UINT32_MAX};
};

uint32 Random::DrawNumber()
{
    return uniform_dist(eng);
}

uint32 Random::DrawNumber(uint32 ub)
{
    return uniform_dist(eng, decltype(uniform_dist)::param_type(0, ub));
}

int main()
{
  Random r;
  std::cout << r.DrawNumber() << std::endl;
  std::cout << r.DrawNumber(42) << std::endl;
}
```