# Mercenne Twister engine performance with varying upperbound

Tags: c++

I have a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036141/vary-range-of-uniform-int-distribution).

To summarize ,
I want to a random number generated in a function call, in the range `[0 maxVal]`. The upper bound (`maxVal`) is different everytime function is called. I tried to test the performance of the code in the answer and my own way to generate a random number (with a wrapper around `std::mt19937`)

According to my performance tests, using a uniform_int_distribution object in the function gives me inferior performance.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class CustomMtRand
{

private:

    std::mt19937 mtRandEngine;

public:

    CustomMtRand(int seed) :mtRandEngine(seed) {}
    //range [0, maxVal - 1]
    unsigned int randomInt(unsigned int maxVal)
    {
        assert(maxVal != 0); //do not pass in 0 as maxVal.
        auto randVal = mtRandEngine(); // generates in range [0 4294967295]
        double scaling = (randVal / 4294967296.0);
        unsigned int retVal = std::floor(maxVal * scaling);
        return retVal;
    }
};

int main()
{

    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::duration;
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;


    CustomMtRand customMtRand(0);


    constexpr int numTests = 5;
    duration<double, std::milli> sumCustom(0);
    duration<double, std::milli> sumMtRand(0);

    for (int j = 0; j < numTests; j++)
    {
        constexpr long numTestIters = 0xffffff;

        auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (auto i = 0; i < numTestIters; i++)
        {
            auto rand = 1 + std::rand() % 10;
            customMtRand.randomInt(rand);

        }
        auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration<double, std::milli> execTime = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << "Custom Rand          :" << execTime.count() << " ms\n";
        sumCustom += execTime;

        std::mt19937 mtRandEngine;
        t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (auto i = 0; i < numTestIters; i++)
        {
            unsigned int rand = 1 + std::rand() % 10;
            std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>{0, rand}(mtRandEngine);
        }
        t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        execTime = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << "MT Rand              :" << execTime.count() << " ms\n";
        sumMtRand += execTime;
    }

    std::cout << "--------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Custom Rand Average  :" << (sumCustom.count() / numTests) << " ms\n";
    std::cout << "MT Rand Average      :" << (sumMtRand.count() / numTests) << " ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example result

```
Custom Rand          :216.012 ms
MT Rand              :297.231 ms
Custom Rand          :217.576 ms
MT Rand              :315.173 ms
Custom Rand          :216.519 ms
MT Rand              :324.193 ms
Custom Rand          :214.586 ms
MT Rand              :302.604 ms
Custom Rand          :213.5 ms
MT Rand              :296.29 ms
--------------------------------
Custom Rand Average  :215.639 ms
MT Rand Average      :307.098 ms
```

I have two questions.

1. Is the way I am testing this correct?
2. If this is correct, is there an alternative to writing a wrapper?

EDIT:
I ran the code on quick-bench.com.
Here is what I tried

```
static void cRandCall(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  CustomMtRand customMtRand(0);
   for (auto _ : state) {
     unsigned int rand = 1 + std::rand() % 10;
     int result = customMtRand.randomInt(rand);
     benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(cRandCall);


static void mtRandCall(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured
   std::mt19937 mtRandEngine;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    unsigned int rand = 1 + std::rand() % 10;
    int result = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>{0, rand}(mtRandEngine);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(mtRandCall);
```

My code still appears to be little bit faster.

[image]

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: you arent using the results so you cannot be sure what parts are optimized away once you do turn on optimizations. Benchmarking isnt that simple. I suggest to use this: https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: You also have an issue where `uniform_int_distribution` gives you the range `[min, max]`, where yours does `[0, max)`

Comment: Don't time with `high_resolution_clock`. It promises high resolution, not accuracy. For example, it might not be monotonic and could jitter around. [Here's the advice of one of the people most responsible for modern C++ time-keeping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37440647/4581301)

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe so. I am running on visual studio, I see the flags /O2 - maximum optimization(Favor speed) . Yes you are right. My range is incorrect, but I believe this shouldn't change the result of any performance test.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks for pointing this out!. This is exacly the reason. I made it `volatile int result = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>{0, rand}(mtRandEngine); `. I believe assigning to a volatile variable will make sure the compiler doesnt optimize it. Now mine is slower :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number On quick-bench.com , though, mine appears to be faster.

Comment: Before you worry about which is faster, you should perform a statistical analysis on yours to prove it’s actually generating the numbers uniformly. Fast is useless if it’s not correct.

Comment: @Taekahn I think it can be shown mathematically than mine folllows the same distibution as the mercene twister engine.

Comment: `std::rand() % 10;` is certainly not uniform. Only if `RAND_MAX % 10 == 0` it is uniform. Consider eg `RAND_MAX % 10 == 2` then `1` and `2` appear once more often than the other results

Comment: @Taekahn Now I see what you are saying, yes I although mine appears to be a sampled version of Mercenne Twister, I am not sure if it is really uniform. The documentation says it is k-distributed. I am not a statistics expert, so I really dont know what this means. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, But I added that just to 'simulate' varying the upper bound. I encountered this issue when writing an MCTS AI for a game I am developing. I think just using mtRandEngine and uniform_int_distribution is enough because its certainly not worse enough to warrant writing a new class instead of a heavily tested method.  So I will not be using my method. Thanks!

Comment: @torres you should have a look at the squirrel3 rng.

Comment: @torres right, i didnt read carefully enough